# How to export all the source code from Visual Studio into a text file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, export, resharper

I have a relatively large Visual Studio solution.

**I need to export all the source code into a text file. I would also want to include a file name somewhere. How can I do so?**

For example if I have a type

```
namespace MyProject.Core
{
    /// <summary>
    ///   Enumerates possible record status
    /// </summary>
    public enum RecordType
    {
        NonWearTime = 0,
        WearTime = 1,
        NotClassified = 2
    }
}
```

I want this to go to the `output.txt` file (or any other text format) and appear like so

```
//***********************************
//Filename: RecordType.cs
//***********************************
namespace MyProject.Core
{
    /// <summary>
    ///   Enumerates possible record status
    /// </summary>
    public enum RecordType
    {
        NonWearTime = 0,
        WearTime = 1,
        NotClassified = 2
    }
}
```

All the other types shall just be appended to the end of the file. I tried Resharper, but its header file options can only contain static text (I tried `Filename: $FILENAME$`) and the template option only applies to the newly created classes.

Folks, this is a study project, where I have to provide the source code along with a thesis.

Comment: I am sorry, but I can't help myself from asking . . . why? Why do you need to do this?

Comment: @oleksii - Many thanks for your fairness with the up votes. I never know whether it's worth answering these questions as invariably most answers are similar, and all within a short space of time as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
string rootPath = @"path you your root folder";
var header = "***********************************" + Environment.NewLine;

var files = Directory.GetFiles(rootPath, "*.cs", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

var result = files.Select(path => new { Name = Path.GetFileName(path), Contents = File.ReadAllText(path)})
                  .Select(info =>   
                      header
                    + "Filename: " + info.Name + Environment.NewLine
                    + header
                    + info.Contents);


var singleStr = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result);
Console.WriteLine ( singleStr );
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\output.txt", singleStr, Encoding.UTF8);
```

Remarks: if you experience performance or memory inefficiencies, try to use `StringBuilder` instead and set it's Capacity at the start to the sum of all files contents. This will eliminate lots of redundant strings, created in last `Select` method.

Answer (score 2):

I would go for a homemade solution.

This helps you get into a String the content of each file.

```
using System.IO;
...
foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderPath, "*.cs"))
{
    string contents = File.ReadAllText(file);
}
```

You have the filename, so you can append it at the beginning.

All you still need to do is to parse through all directories.

```
   public void DirSearch(string root)
   {

           foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(root, "*.cs"))
           {
                    string contents = File.ReadAllText(file);
                    // Write to your outputfile once you've happened what you want in your header.
           }

           foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(root))
           {
               DirSearch(d);
           }
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

As a none code soloution how about trying a **windows command line** to merge all files into one.

e.g. copy /b *.cs newfile.txt

https://superuser.com/questions/111825/any-command-line-or-batch-cmd-to-concatenate-multiple-files

Admittedly its quick and dirty, but it might produce what you require with some tailoring

Answer (score 1):

I would write a simple console app to do that. It would search for all files with a *.cs extension, make the necessary modification and then save the file to the desired location. You can loop through directories iteratively using `Directory.EnumerateDirectories()`.